# Can I re-use a DialogFragment instance or should I create I new one for a DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, instance, android-datepicker

So I create a `DatePickerFragment` for a user to enter a date on an `EditText` line when the `EditText` is empty:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   if (xEditText.getText().length() == 0) {
   DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
   newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

Later, if the `EditText` is not empty (because the user previously entered a date) then I want to send the date in a bundle to the fragment:

```
else {
     ...        
     Bundle argsbundle = new Bundle();
     argsbundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
     ...
```

My question is should I create a new instance of the `DatePickerFragment` with the  previously named `newFragment` in the `else {` statement:

```
else {
     ...        
     Bundle argsbundle = new Bundle();
     argsbundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
     DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
     newFragment.setArguments(argsbundle);
     newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Or should I be creating a newly named Fragment, different from `newFragment`:

```
     else {
     ...        
     Bundle argsbundle = new Bundle();
     argsbundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
     DatePickerFragment secondFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
     secondFragment.setArguments(argsbundle);
     secondFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Comment: Still question is not clear to me :(. Can you please explain me little bit what is actual problem you getting while using same fragment or its just a design you wanna discuss.

Comment: code runs fine I am just wondering from a design standpoint and memory usage if I should be creating Fragment instance with the same name or better to use a different name.